# How to sign transaction for two usdt receivers (same sender)?

Tags: web3js, polygon, usdt

I have a working code for creating a signed USDT transaction using web3js, but I am not successful in adding another receiver in the same signed transaction. How can I send USDT to two separate addresses in the same signed transaciton?

The current code (that only sendt to the first receiver):

```js
const { Web3 } = require('web3');

const privateKey = 'xxxxxxxx';
const usdtContractAddress = '0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f';



const options = {
  keepAlive: true,
  withCredentials: false,
  timeout: 20000, // ms
  headers: [
    {
      name: 'x-nonce',
      value: '123123123123123123'
    },
  ]
};

const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
  'http://localhost:8110/polygon/rpc',
  options,
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const createSignedTransactionForNewContract = async (receivers, amounts, contractAddress) => {
  const senderAddress = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey).address;
  console.log('sender address: '+senderAddress);

  // Get the nonce
  const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddress, 'latest');
  let contractAbi = '';
  try {
    // Dynamically fetch the contract ABI

    contractAbi = [
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_spender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "success",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "totalSupply",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_from",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "transferFrom",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "success",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "decimals",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "version",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_owner",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "balance",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "symbol",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "success",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_spender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          },
          {
            "name": "_extraData",
            "type": "bytes"
          }
        ],
        "name": "approveAndCall",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "success",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_owner",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_spender",
            "type": "address"
          }
        ],
        "name": "allowance",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "remaining",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "type": "function"
      },
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_initialAmount",
            "type": "uint256"
          },
          {
            "name": "_tokenName",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "_decimalUnits",
            "type": "uint8"
          },
          {
            "name": "_tokenSymbol",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "type": "constructor"
      },
      {
        "payable": false,
        "type": "fallback"
      },
      {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_from",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": false,
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
      },
      {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_owner",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_spender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "indexed": false,
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Approval",
        "type": "event"
      },
    ];

    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);


    const transferUSDTData = contract.methods.transfer(receivers, amounts).encodeABI();


    let gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();

    console.log('Gas price: '+gasPrice);

    // Create the transaction object
    const txObject = {
      from: senderAddress,
      to: contractAddress,
      nonce: nonce,
      gasPrice: gasPrice,
      //gasLimit: 50000, // Adjust the gas limit based on your needs
      data: transferUSDTData
    };

    // Sign the transaction
    const signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txObject, privateKey);

    return signedTransaction.rawTransaction;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    throw error; // Re-throw the error for further handling if needed
  }
};

let amountInDecimal = 0.01;
const amount = amountInDecimal * 1000000;

// Example usage
const receiver1 = '0x7Cc3f71459aAD6c556f35189fE89E63F737A4b76';
const receiver2 = '0xCE7F9CC7bf2DC89d5968619303C0484f25eba352';
const receivers = [receiver1,receiver2];
const amounts = [amount,amount];
createSignedTransactionForNewContract(receivers, amounts,usdtContractAddress)
  .then(rawTransaction => {
    console.log('Signed Transaction:', rawTransaction);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

Comment: You can't do this from an EOA. You would need an intermediate contract that has a method to send it to the two recipients

Comment: Look here this might help: https://github.com/encoderafat/disperse